# Using MessageDispatcherServlet vs wiring up Spring-WS in a DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, web-services

As I was going through the spring reference for Webservices, I got to know that there are two ways to implement jax-ws webservices in spring.

One is by using MessageDispatcherContext, which I found is the easiest way to go about.

And the other way is to wire Spring-ws in a DispatcherServlet using some adapters like WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter and SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter etc.

I couldn't understand the need of this second approach as at first, it looks a bit complex to me.
Please help me understand why I should use this second approach and given a scenario which approach is best suited.

Thank you.

Comment: do you know why we use DispatcherServelet ?

Comment: Yes... it is to dispatch the requests for the controller, which follows the "Front Controller" pattern. And MessageDispatcherServlet also follows similar pattern, to dispatch messages to Endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question lies in the Spring Webservices documentation itself :

`The message dispatcher operates on a message context`, `and not transport-specific input stream and output stream`.

As a result, transport specific requests need to read into a MessageContext.

`For HTTP, this is done with a WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter`, which is a Spring Web HandlerInterceptor`, so that the MessageDispatcher can be wired in a standard DispatcherServlet.

> http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html

You should use `WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter` because in most cases the Transport is HTTP/S . However if your application serves as Service Bus like Mule - MessageDispatcher is more suited

Comment: Thank you for details and reference. But why you consider using DispatcherServelt as the best way, as MessageDispatcherServlet is transport agnostic and can be handled for any transport.. and moreover, it is simple as well...